# CarrierWaver error in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, production, minimagick

I am using AWS S3 for file storage in production. Whenever, I try to upload a file using carrier wave and MiniMagick, I get an error. Here is my latest log:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4045ms (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
Excon::Errors::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
excon.error.response
:body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error>    <Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>  <RequestId>DCF69609EFC07D35</RequestId>  <HostId>9yQPgVg+/ejnbR7gTgWqWILl0Ae+eUlKMJhwIjATe3ctav1CkuyaxSCE38rWJteASzPvaBX6  8KY=</HostId></Error>"
:headers       => {
"Connection"       => "close"
"Content-Type"     => "application/xml"
"Date"             => "Tue, 26 Apr 2016 19:25:20 GMT"
"Server"           => "AmazonS3"
"x-amz-id-2"       => "9yQPgVg+/ejnbR7gTgWqWILl0Ae+eUlKMJhwIjATe3ctav1CkuyaxSCE38rWJteASzPvaBX68KY="
"x-amz-request-id" => "DCF69609EFC07D35"
}
:local_address => "46.101.134.74"
:local_port    => 56549
:reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
:remote_ip     => "54.231.176.121"
:status        => 403
:status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
):
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:58:in `block in update'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:57:in `update'
```

Comment: did u open permission for aws ? make it public.

Comment: No let me try that

Comment: Is it about granting List/Update/Edit permissions for the bucket ?

Comment: I am just a little not sure. Do you mean the bucket permissions ?

Comment: yes, i was meaning that. if not work can u post your carrierwave s3 configurations.

Comment: it worked. Thanks. I had to grant administration privileges  to the user.

Comment: do u want me to answer it with example ?

Comment: Yeah sure it could help future developers facing the same issue.